# Having trouble with this : Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php'

Tags: php, api, email, composer-php, google-cloud-platform

I have tried using oAuth2 to use the google cloud platform api, but my redirect url(get_oauth_token.php in PHPMailer is the file I used) couldn't find composer's autoload file : vendor/autoload.php, even though I have composer and guzzle downloaded and running. Are there any other files that I should download or another way to autoload that file?

Here's get_oauth_token.php in case you haven't seen it(didn't post client id on here)

```
<?php
/**
 * Get an OAuth2 token from Google.
 * * Install this script on your server so that it's accessible
 * as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
 * e.g.: http://localhost/phpmail/get_oauth_token.php
 * * Ensure dependencies are installed with 'composer install'
 * * Set up an app in your Google developer console
 * * Set the script address as the app's redirect URL
 * If no refresh token is obtained when running this file, revoke access to your app
 * using link: https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens and run the script again.
 * This script requires PHP 5.4 or later
 * PHP Version 5.4
 */

namespace League\OAuth2\Client\Provider;
//composer require PHPMailer/PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//require_once(__DIR__.'/PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/vendor/autoload.php');

use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Token\AccessToken;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Tool\BearerAuthorizationTrait;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;

session_start();

//If this automatic URL doesn't work, set it yourself manually
$redirectUri ='http://localhost:8080/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php';
//$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/phpmailer/get_oauth_token.php';

//These details obtained are by setting up app in Google developer console.
$clientId = '';
$clientSecret = '';

class Google extends AbstractProvider
{
    use BearerAuthorizationTrait;

    const ACCESS_TOKEN_RESOURCE_OWNER_ID = 'id';

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "access_type" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline
     */
    protected $accessType;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "hd" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#hd-param
     */
    protected $hostedDomain;

    /**
     * @var string If set, this will be sent to google as the "scope" parameter.
     * @link https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes
     */
    protected $scope;

    public function getBaseAuthorizationUrl()
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
    }

    public function getBaseAccessTokenUrl(array $params)
    {
        return 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
    }

    public function getResourceOwnerDetailsUrl(AccessToken $token)
    {
    return ' ';
    }

    protected function getAuthorizationParameters(array $options)
    {
    if (is_array($this->scope)) {
            $separator = $this->getScopeSeparator();
            $this->scope = implode($separator, $this->scope);
        }

        $params = array_merge(
            parent::getAuthorizationParameters($options),
            array_filter([
                'hd'          => $this->hostedDomain,
                'access_type' => $this->accessType,
        'scope'       => $this->scope,
                // if the user is logged in with more than one account ask which one to use for the login!
                'authuser'    => '-1'
            ])
        );
        return $params;
    }

    protected function getDefaultScopes()
    {
        return [
            'email',
            'openid',
            'profile',
        ];
    }

    protected function getScopeSeparator()
    {
        return ' ';
    }

    protected function checkResponse(ResponseInterface $response, $data)
    {
        if (!empty($data['error'])) {
            $code  = 0;
            $error = $data['error'];

            if (is_array($error)) {
                $code  = $error['code'];
                $error = $error['message'];
            }

            throw new IdentityProviderException($error, $code, $data);
        }
    }

    protected function createResourceOwner(array $response, AccessToken $token)
    {
        return new GoogleUser($response);
    }
}


//Set Redirect URI in Developer Console as [https/http]://<yourdomain>/<folder>/get_oauth_token.php
$provider = new Google(
    array(
        'clientId' => $clientId,
        'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirectUri' => $redirectUri,
        'scope' => array('https://mail.google.com/'),
    'accessType' => 'offline'
    )
);

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // If we don't have an authorization code then get one
    $authUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();
    $_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();
    header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    exit;
// Check given state against previously stored one to mitigate CSRF attack
} elseif (empty($_GET['state']) || ($_GET['state'] !== $_SESSION['oauth2state'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['oauth2state']);
    exit('Invalid state');
} else {
    // Try to get an access token (using the authorization code grant)
    $token = $provider->getAccessToken(
        'authorization_code',
        array(
            'code' => $_GET['code']
        )
    );

    // Use this to get a new access token if the old one expires
    echo 'Refresh Token: ' . $token->getRefreshToken();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be forgeting the file path in this case. 
Try `require "/path/to/vendor/autoload.php";`

Comment: I'm not even sure what path to put since I don't have it saved as a file but since I installed composer and guzzle it should have installed that package

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: Ok, well it is worth a try. Trying finding out where the default installation directory is for composer and guzzle. if you are more daring and patient, you could try searching for autoload.php in your file browser. Once found, put in the path to it, and it should work. Also, perhaps you could try a manual installation of it?

Comment: thanks I found the file and now the url works but when trying to fetch the token I get this error :                                                                        Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate  problem: unable to get local issuer certificate                                      I've downloaded the latest cacert.pem file and added this line to my php.ini file : curl.cainfo=/path/to/downloaded/cacert.pem with the right path, what else should I do?

Comment: I actually am uncertain as to how to solve that issue, however, there are a few things which appear to be off to me, for one, you are on port 8080 instead of 80 for your redirect uri. To be honest, I would be more helpful if you were on Linux, sorry man. I would suggest asking it as a separate question on here.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it did answer your original question! It definitely seems to be a configuration issue for the second problem. I don't think you would need to add that to your php.ini file to get it to work.